# SUMPRODUCT Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

[image: SCREENSHOT 1]

[image: SCREENSHOT 2]

I'm trying to use SUMPRODUCT or any other formula to get an end calculation of how many occurences "Louise" appears in column F and then how many Sessions she had in the MONTH of September and YEAR 2022 from columns F, N, O, P, Q, V, W, AA, AB and AC.

I need to pull the data from a sheet called 'WHSS Service Details' (Screenshot 2) onto a sheet called Staff Sessions (Screenshot 1) where Louise has her name and then every month of the year listed.
So the final total should be, say, 13.

My test formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($F$3:$F$200="Louise")*(MONTH($N$3:$N$200)=AJ2)*(YEAR($N$3:$N$200)=$AH$1))
```

works on the 'WHSS Service Details" sheet, but I dont know how to add more columns to my query, such as columns O, P, Q etc. I have only got N here.

I have tried the formula in 'WHSS Service Details'and it always seems to be +1 digit off.

[image: SCREENSHOT 3]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Sorry, we can't accept images of code or errors. Post those as text, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Some diagrams of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question.